# MapStruct: map an entity with a field of the same type of the entity

Tags: mapstruct

consider this situation:

```
public class Car() {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private Car car;
}

public class CarDTO() {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private Long carId;
}
```

I tried to map from DTO to Entity with this:

```
@Mapping(target = "car", source = "carId")
Car toEntity(CarDTO carDTO);
```

but it don't works.
So, how can I map an entity with a field of the same type of the entity?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 3):

```
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "carDTO.carId")
Car toEntity(CarDTO carDTO);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered in the MapStruct [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapstruct-users/HFsQeQeQIF0)

Depending on what you need. You can either do:

```
@Mapping(target = "car.id", source = "carId")
Car toEntity(CarDTO carDTO);
```

If there is more magic involved in creating a `Car` from the `carId`, you can do that part manually:

```
@Mapping(target = "car", source = "carId")
Car toEntity(CarDTO carDTO);

default Car resolve(Long id) { 
    return /* something fancy */; 
}
```

The something fancy can also be a DB call to fetch a `Car` from there.